# Concatenation of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I'm looking to add to a string's value based on the output for multiple if statements but I don't seem to be having much success. I've declared comp_string="" at the beginning of the script then tried += so that for each condition that is true it adds a section on.

For the code example below if I submitted the value of www.facebook.com and www.twitter.com I would like comp_string to return 'fb=www.facebook.com&tw=www.twitter.com'

How would I go about concatenating/adding the string together and how do I add the & if more than one link is provided. I could add it to each string for any value thats not blank, but would an & on the end of the url with nothing following mess things up?

```
if (facebook_url != "") {
    comp_string += "fb="+facebook_url;
}

if (twitter_url != "") {
    comp_string += "tw="+twitter_url;
}

alert(comp_string);
```

Comment: Inside each `if` after the first one, you could use `if (comp_string != "") comp_string+= "&";` before concat the url string.

Comment: Besides, if you need to open a question to know how to do this kind of logic, you need to think for yourself what you're doing into developing world, if you don't want to melt your brain when find a problem.

Comment: Firstly I seem to be having issues using the += operator which is why I waas querying how to concatinate. When looking up javascript concatination the only examples I was finding was add numbers to strings, or combining the output of var a with var b, not adding to the sting stored within a variable.

 If that is the right operator I'm using then my issue must lie else where. As for adding the & sign it was something I though about whilst creating the post so thought I'd ask in the hope of a more elegant soloution that nested if's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be to add each string to an array, then join the array elements to produce the end result you are looking for.

```
var params = [];

if (facebook_url !== "") {
  params.push("fb=" + facebook_url);
}

if (twitter_url !== "") {
  params.push("tw=" + twitter_url);
}

alert(params.join("&"));
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Thank you for a helpfull and elegant soloution